# replacing a custom tag's value with a string in php

Tags: php

I want to read a html file and replace what ever is inside mytag.

so in html file we have something like this :

```
                    <div>
                        <h3><mytag>_THIS_DAY</mytag></h3>
                        <div>
                             [LOGIN]
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and then in php file , i need to read the file and replace the values inside  tags.

str_replace() ?

how to get the value inside those tags in php and then how to replace them with something like a string ?

Answer (score 2):

`str_replace()` uses regular expressions, which (as noted [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) on this site) are usually insufficient for parsing HTML.

You should use an [HTML parser](http://docs.php.net/manual/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to retrieve and/or replace the required values.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning: [You shouldn't parse XHTML with regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)**

That said, you can still do it:

```
preg_replace("~(?<=<mytag>)[^>]+(?=</mytag>)~", "independance day", $yourHtml);
```

Quick explanation:

- `[^>]+` We look for a string of 1+ char and without `>`
- `(?<=<mytag>)` This string must be after `<mytag>` ([positive
  lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))
- `(?=</mytag>)` This string must be folowed by `</mytag>` (positive
  lookbehind)

[Live example](http://codepad.org/TKt6qOtO)

Answer (score 1):

- take a look in the php-manual fpr preg_replace. with a regex you can perform a simple replacement
- if you want to something more complex, you can parse your html. you can use for example the simple_html_dom-contribution: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/